# Using Mockito in Scala with Spec2

Tags: scala, mockito

This is in the context of Play framework. I have a controller that instantiates a Validator. Validator has validate method. Controller has a method putEnity() that validates the payload it receives using this validate().

For unit testing the controller, i would like to mock the call Validator.validate(). TestController looks like this

```
class EntityControllerTest extends FlatSpec with Mockito {
def testPutEntity() = {
  val payload = createPayload()
  val mockValidator = mock[Validator]
  when(mockValidator.validate(anyString, anyString)).thenReturn(EntityValidationResult(true, "Test"))                                            
  EntityController.putEntity(payload)
}
```

The problem is that, this mock call is not being used but the actual validate() is called and hence the test fails.

How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your final line:

```
EntityController.putEntity(payload)
```

you are effectively calling a static method on `EntityController`, and despite all your attempts to configure a mock `Validator` you've never had an opportunity to "inject it" into the controller.

It's going to be a little bit difficult to suggest an ideal solution without seeing how you've implemented your controller, but at a guess, you'd want to do something like the following to allow a mocked `Validator` to be injected for testing, but for everything else to work like before.

I'll step through it to (hopefully) make it clearer:

#### Step 1 - make `EntityController` instantiable:

You've probably got something like this:

```
object EntityController extends Controller {
   ...
   def putEntity = Action ...
   ..
}
```

Replace it with this:

```
class EntityControl extends Controller {
   ...
   def putEntity = Action ...
   ...
}

object EntityController extends EntityControl
```

Now you've given yourself the ability to `new` something with the same behaviour as your "production" object. But we need to be able to substitute in a mock validator...

#### Step 2 - require a validator instance in your `EntityControl`:

Your old `EntityController` object probably had something like this:

```
object EntityController extends Controller {
  val validator = new Validator(...)
  ...
}
```

which is why you could never get your mocked validator involved. Let's inject it as a constructor parameter so it can't be forgotten:

```
class EntityControl(val validator:Validator) extends Controller {
   ...
}

object EntityController extends EntityControl(new Validator(...))
```

So again, our "production" `EntityController` object has all the functionality we used to have, but the key difference is that we've exposed a ["testing seam"](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.au/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html) to allow a mock to be injected when needed.

#### Step 3 - inject, and test!

Flip to your test spec, and set up a testable `EntityControl` instance

```
class EntityControllerTest extends FlatSpec with Mockito {

  def testPutEntity() = {
    val payload = createPayload()
    val mockValidator = mock[Validator]
    when(mockValidator.validate(anyString, anyString)).thenReturn(EntityValidationResult(true, "Test"))  

    val myTestableEC = new EntityControl(mockValidator)                                          
    myTestableEC.putEntity(payload)
}
```

As you develop more test cases, you'll probably want to extract the setup-and-wiring parts of the test into a suitable function, or even a [Specs2 `Scope`](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Scope).

Hope this helps, and clarifies a few effective unit testing ideas for you too.